# Hyperledger Fabric syntax for an array of concepts in setupDemo?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hyperledger-fabric

I have an asset `foo`
and this asset has an array of concepts `bar` with two attributes `icecream` and `price`
whats the syntax for creating dummy data in the setupDemo transaction?

This is what I have right now but it throws an error 
`TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

```
const foo = factory.newResource(NS, 'Foo','F001');
const barr = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Bar');
barr.icecream = 'Chocolate';
barr.price = 0.50;
foo.bar[0] = barr;
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I will answer my own question.

```
const foo = factory.newResource(NS, 'Foo','F001');
const bar1 = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Bar');
const bar2 = factory.newConcept(NS, 'Bar');
```

Although bar is defined as an array in the .cto file, `typeof` returns it as undefined. Therefore it is needed to create another array and then pass it.

```
let barArray = [];
bar1.icecream = 'Chocolate';
bar1.price = 0.14;
bar2.icecream = 'Vanilla';
bar2.price = 0.25;
barArray.push(bar1, bar2);
foo.bar =  barArray;
```